# Word for submission of evidence?

Tags: word-choice

I was reading an article about Elie Wiesel's memoir( novel ? ), Night. It argues that his memoir( novel ? ), was falsified. His response was that it was "his ___".

The underlined is a word that when I searched up, was something along the lines of 'submission of evidence'. I cannot research, or trace my tracks, to find the word. Any help is welcomed.

Additionally, if anyone can help me clarify the genre (memoir or novel) of this, it would be good. I am hesitant to classify it as "novel" in my essay, as it could possibly be taken the wrong way as in holocaust-denying wrong way.

I have come to be a bit more emotionally vested into finding this word than I'd anticipated (1:58 AM and still looking, argh)

Cheers,

Comment: He might have said it was his ***testimony*** (or with a bit more "gravitas" and religious connotations, his ***testament***).

Comment: Or it could have been anything else, including any suitable metaphor involving books, memories, defeats, whatever. I think this question may be too broad, however specific it seems to be.

Comment: @Robusto - Too broad? How so? The OP asked what the missing word was that was contained in a specific statement by Wiesel. It was not a request for speculations about what a suitable word *might be*.

Comment: @ErikKowal: Yet speculation is precisely what, to judge from some of the answers below, it seems to have solicited.

Comment: @Robusto - But that is not the fault of the OP. There is *only one right answer;* the other suggestions were made by people who apparently had not researched this particular utterance of Wiesel's and/or who decided to post an alternative possibility despite the correct answer already having been given. (I think such an impulse could still be useful to some future enquirer looking for synonyms for 'deposition'.)

Comment: @ErikKowal: And I am not blaming the OP (you have enough rep to see that there are no downvotes, hence I could not have downvoted). I am merely observing that the way the question's title currently reads may constitute an invitation for people to speculate. A good many people don't read past the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_(book)) which discusses the book states:

> He has called it his **deposition**, but scholars have had difficulty approaching it as an unvarnished account.

As for the genre, **memoir** is appropriate if the work is taken at face value.

If the work has partly been made up, Wiesel could be said to have **reimagined** the events described in it. I'm not sure there is a generic descriptor for such accounts, though **fake memoir** or even **fake autobiography** spring to mind.

Comment: Eureka! That was the word.

Answer (score 0):

You are perhaps looking for [Deposition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/deposition?searchDictCode=all).

> Law: The process of giving sworn evidence:
>   the deposition of four expert witnesses
>
> Law: A formal, usually written, statement to be used as evidence.

Answer (score 0):

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_%28book%29#Reception) for *Night* has a subsection titled "Memoir or Novel." The first paragraph of this section states:

> Wiesel called *Night* his deposition. Reviewers have nevertheless had difficulty reading it as an eyewitness account. It has been called a novel, autobiography, autobiographical novel, non-fictional novel, semi-fictional memoir, fictional-autobiographical novel, fictionalized autobiographical memoir and memoir-novel. Ellen Fine calls it *témoignage* (testimony). Lawrence Langer writes that the book is "ballasted with the freight of fiction: scenic organization, characterization through dialogue, periodic climaxes, elimination of superfluous or repetitive episodes ..."

As others have pointed out, calling it a **deposition** shows that Wiesel presents the information as true. **Testimony** means much the same thing and has a similar legal connotation.

The other terms suggested in the above quote would work as well. Since you hesitate to call it a memoir, but don't want to write it off completely as a novel, I think **autobiographical novel** or **semi-fictional memoir** work best to describe its standing as "based on fact but not 100% true."

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot speak to the term used in the article, consider *proffer*. Both a verb and a noun, its common meaning is

> Hold out (something) to someone for acceptance; offer *[Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/proffer)*

It is also used in law. One of its meanings in that context is

> to offer evidence in a trial. *[law.com](http://dictionary.law.com/Default.aspx?letter=P)*

The term *[bear witness](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bear-witness)* is also often used for the process of testifying, even in a non-legal context, to things that have occurred or must be acknowledged. See examples in *Collins*